# Random sampling of 30 rows for each column

Tags: mysql, random, sampling

I have a very simple MySQL table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE tdata (
    id varchar(256),
    color varchar(256)
);
```

This table has data like

```
bill,orange
bill,orange
bill,umber
(...)
bill,yellow
jerry,blue
jerry,purple
(...)
jerry,blue
```

Each id has a number of colors which are not guaranteed unique. I'm looking to select a unique random sample of 20 colors for each id, such that the output would look like:

```
bill,orange
bill,umber
(...)
bill,chartreuse
jerry,blue
(and so on)
```

Each id may have less or more than 20 colors, but if more than 20 are returned I would like to discard the rest.

The full table is almost 100k rows, so I can't specify each ID in the query. Is there an elegant MySQL query to do this?

Comment: You have a big problem with your data. Each pair of values should be unique.

Comment: This is human-generated data.  I could easily make each row unique by selecting DISTINCT the whole thing, if that helps the answer. It's iterating through the ids and selecting 20 unique colors for EACH id that's breaking my brain.

Comment: If you actually want 20 _unique_ colors per name `id`, then you should update your question and let us know if each `id` is even guaranteed to have 20 distinct colors.  Also, what logic do you want to use for deciding which `id` gets which color, assuming that colors are shared between `id`s.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get your result with some very heavy dynamic SQL, far above the deleted query which I gave below.  Why do you need this result?  Have you thought about changing your data structure so that you don't need such complex queries?

Comment: Tim, I updated the question. Each ID is not guaranteed to have 20 unique colors. This data comes from humans, so it was not generated logically. It looked like your earlier response was VERY close, the only problem was that it didn't return <=20 colors per ID.

Comment: No, my answer was nowhere near what you need, because it returns only distinct colors _within each id_.  You want to globally return only unique colors and the logic you want for doing this isn't even clear.

Comment: Tim, distinct colors within each id is _exactly_ what I need. I just need to get <= 20 of them per id.